# EventHandlers and the sender

Tags: c#, events, handler, event-handling, sender

So in my program i created a struct with a button and a number value... like this

```
struct box
    {
        public int numberValue;
        public Button button;
    }
```

I then made a 2D array of this struct

```
box[,] boxes = new box[20, 20];
```

Now what i did was make 400 buttons and assigned them to each index of the array... like this

```
        private void createBoxes()
    {
        int positionX;
        int positionY;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            {
                positionX = 20 + (25 * i);
                positionY = 20 + (25 * j);
                boxes[i, j].button = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
                boxes[i, j].button.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(positionX,positionY);
                boxes[i, j].button.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 25);
                this.Controls.Add(boxes[i, j].button);
                boxes[i, j].button.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
                boxes[i, j].button.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                boxes[i, j].button.Visible = true;
                boxes[i, j].button.Name = "button";
                boxes[i, j].button.Click += new EventHandler(buttonClick);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now when i make the event handler i want to send "boxes[i,j]" not just "boxes[i,j].button" is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Short of defining your own anonymous event handler, there's an easy way to do what you want:

```
boxes[i, j].button.Tag = boxes[i, j];
```

Then later:

```
private void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var box = ((Button)sender).Tag as box;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved via an anonymous event handler.

```
var box = boxes[i, j]; // You must use a new variable within this scope
box.button.Click += (obj, args) => buttonClick(box, args);
```

This is the quickest solution with the least code. Just be aware that anonymous event handlers are notorious for hidden gotchas, and the need to assign a new *box* variable is an example. The following code will run, but no matter which button you press, the last-assigned values of *i* and *j* would be used within the handler.

```
boxes[i,j].button.Click += (obj, args) => buttonClick(boxes[i,j], args);
```

Comment: This, of course, will make it extremely difficult to *unsubscribe* from that event later.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. The individual button control is the one that raises the event, thus it is the object referenced by the `sender` parameter. The array that *contains* the button control is irrelevant.

This behavior is by-design. If you wanted to change a property of the button in response to the user clicking on it, it would be impossible to do unless you knew *which* individual button was clicked. Having only a reference to the array that contains all of the buttons would not provide sufficient information about the individual button that was clicked.